# A question about TransactionManager, spring-session-jdbc and seperate datasource

Tags: spring-session, transactionmanager

I'm using spring-session-jdbc to store HTTP sessions in a PostgreSQL database. I have another primary DataSource for my application.

When using @SpringSessionDataSource, you can define a different DataSource for Spring Session. However, by default, the TransactionManager in JdbcIndexedSessionRepository is created with the primary DataSource.

For now, I am using a bean TransactionOperations.withoutTransaction() to avoid the transaction in Spring Session. However, I think it could be a problem, or I might be missing something.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an actual question here, but I confirm that I have the same or similar problem - the `JdbcIndexedSessionRepository` uses  the `PlatformTransactionManager` to initiate the transaction, which was leading to deadlocks if the connection pool was exhausted (thanks to the `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction propagation). Thanks for the tip, I also used a `WithoutTransactionOperations` for the `springSessionTransactionOperations` to work around the issue.